# How do I create self-referencing relations in laravel nova

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-nova, laravel-10

I have a model named "Product." This product is associated with a category, and each category has numerous features. Additionally, each feature has a considerable number of feature items.

I want to implement a functionality in Laravel where, when a user wants to create a product and selects a category, the associated features and their feature items should be displayed. The user can then specify the characteristics of each feature.

For example:
If the product is clothing in the "Apparel" category, one of the features could be "Size" or "Material." The "Material" feature might have feature items such as "Wool" or "Cotton." The user should be able to specify these details when creating the product.

my model :product,cateogry,feautre,feature_category,and feature_item_product;

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure all the relations between your models are correctly formed. Considering the models you have shared these should be the relations you have to make:

- A `Product` belongs to a `Category`.
- A `Category` has many `FeatureCategory`.
- A `FeatureCategory` has many `Feature`.
- A `Feature` has many `FeatureItem`.
- A `Product` has many `FeatureItemProduct`.

### Controller Logic:

In your controller, when you're handling the creation of a product, retrieve the necessary data to pass to the view. For example:

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    // Load other necessary data like features, feature categories, etc.

    return view('products.create', compact('categories', 'otherData'));
}
```

### View

Then inside your view where you are supposed to handle creation you might need some javascript and AJAX call to fetch data related to category like this:

```
<!-- Your form code -->

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select id="category" name="category_id">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<!-- Add divs/spans to hold dynamic feature and feature item fields -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#category').on('change', function () {
            var categoryId = $(this).val();

            // Make an AJAX request to fetch features and feature items based on the selected category
            $.ajax({
                url: '/get-features/' + categoryId,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    // Update the UI with the retrieved data (e.g., add input fields dynamically)
                    // Use jQuery or vanilla JavaScript to manipulate the DOM
                },
                error: function () {
                    // Handle errors
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

### AJAX Call

Define a route in web.php

```
Route::get('/get-features/{category}', 'ProductController@getFeatures');
```

Now in your ProductController:

```
public function getFeatures(Category $category)
{
    // Retrieve features and feature items based on the selected category
    $features = $category->features()->with('featureItems')->get();

    return response()->json($features);
}
```

Adjust this based on your specific requirement.

### Store

Finally store the created data into database

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Validate and store product data

    // Attach features and feature items to the product
}
```

This is not an actual implementation of your use case and might not work directly without modification. This solution is just to provide you with the basic idea of actual implementation.